# Create json data on iPhone with integers, bools

Tags: iphone, json

Using the json-framework for iPhone (http://code.google.com/p/json-framework/) it's really easy to create json data from a NSDictionary. Like so;

```
NSString *json_string = [json_parser stringWithObject:dictionary];
```

This works perfect if I have objects like NSString and so on in my dictionary. But I also need to send integers,bools and floats with json and can not find a way to do this in the same way. Anyone got a solution?

UPDATE:

I found out that I can wrap integers to NSNumber. But how can I use bools?

Comment: You can wrap BOOL values in NSNumber just like any other numeric type: see numberWithBool:, initWithBool:, and boolValue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that json-framework maps from JSON bools and numbers to `NSDecimalNumber`. In the case of bools, the `NSDecimalNumber` should be init'd with `initWithBool:`. Give that a try.